# FontAwesome not displaying icons on mobile

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

I have problem with using arrows form FontAwesome. Here's how I'm using them:

```
<a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
  <img src="img/pictograms/service2_pic1.png" alt=""><p>Photography</p>
</a>
```

Ad my .scss:

```
a {
    &:after {
      //gora
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      content: "\2303";
      color: $color-grey-dark;
      position: absolute;
      right: 15px;
      top: 27px;
      font-size: 48px;
      @media #{$xs-screen} {
        font-size: 30px;
        top: 32px;
      }
    }

    &.collapsed {
      &:after {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        content: "\2304";
        color: $color-grey-dark;
        position: absolute;
        right: 15px;
        top: -3px;
        font-size: 48px;
        @media #{$xs-screen} {
          font-size: 30px;
          top:13px;
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

It works great on pc but on mobile, instead of nice arrow up/down I'm getting this symbol: http://sketchtoy.com/68196005 (sorry for sketchtoy but it's quicker than seaching for this symbol on my computer :D )

Comment: which mobile you are referring to? Please provide with Brand, Browser, Android Version

Comment: you might want to check the path of the font